# Unlimited savelines in XTerm?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xterm

I'm trying to achieve unlimited or simply very large number of lines saved beyond the top of the screen in XTerm. I do have my `xterm*savelines: 10000000` resource set to a rather large number, and I indeed see the result of increasing `savelines`, but it's not even near the value of 10000000 in practice. Apparently, there seems to be some cap on the number of lines saved and it's not very large (my dmesg doesn't fit for instance). That was never a problem with `konsole`.

Is it possible to increase that number or make it unlimited in XTerm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xterm stores saved-lines in memory, allocates those at startup (or if the window is resized, since the width can vary).  The feature was rewritten starting in 2009 with [patch #244](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_244) to make it more efficient than the original (which was noticeably slow at much lower than 10 million lines).

konsole has a dialog allowing "unlimited" lines, which stores the scrollback on disk (in turn, not really "unlimited", and guaranteed to be slower than an in-memory approach).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation Thomas! However, at the current max buffer size xterm is super fast (I cannot notice any delay) and I am definitely willing to compromise the speed to get a larger buffer. Could you tell me why it's not possible to go beyond some max value?

Comment: It might run out of memory, but there is no hardcoded limit on the number of saved lines.  In a quick check on a machine with 1GB, 20 million lines is too much, but 15 million fits. On the other hand, if the actual limit (as used) were something like 65 thousand, that could be a bug to investigate.

Comment: With a simple test `for i in $(seq 1082); do echo $i; done` I can see that my limit is 1083 lines despite the setting of `xterm*savelines: 10000000`. Is there a simple way to see if XTerm is aware of my setting?

Comment: Ok, `xterm -sl 1000000` does seem to work as expected. I must be doing something wrong with the XResources configuration then I guess?

Comment: Now that is actually embarassing, I think the problem was simply `xterm*savelines` instead of `xterm*saveLines`. Thanks for your help Thomas!